# Add subtotal to checkout button

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add subtotal to the checkout button via the following code

```
add_filter( 'gettext', function( $translated_text ) {

        if ( 'Checkout' === $translated_text ) {
        $subtotal = WC()->cart->get_subtotal();
         $translated_text = "EXPRESS " . $translated_text . " -$" . $subtotal;

    }
    return $translated_text;
} );
```

However, i see the following errors in the logs
Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_subtotal() on null in .......file name.....

Answer (score 0):

needed to add:

```php
if ( ! isset( WC()->cart ) ) return;
```

full code:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', function( $translated_text ) {
        if ( 'Checkout' === $translated_text ) {
        if ( ! isset( WC()->cart ) ) return;
        $subtotal = WC()->cart->get_subtotal();
        $translated_text = "EXPRESS " . $translated_text . " -  $" . $subtotal;
    }
    return $translated_text;
} );
```